# Using derived table in join (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to figure out how to make the below query work. Teradata is giving me the message that it can't find the derived table `GLT_Yearly`. Essentially, I'm trying to manipulate `GLT_Yearly` in the left join as `BD`, then join it on itself. Is what I'm trying to do possible or is there a better way to go about it? Thanks!

```
SELECT
FROM
  (SELECT
   FROM
     (SELECT
      FROM
        (SELECT
         FROM
         )AS GLT0
      )AS GLT1
   )AS GLT_Yearly
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
   FROM GLT_Yearly) AS BD 
   ON Account = BD.Account
```

Comment: Semms you want to implement something like a *Lateral Join* which is not supported in Teradata. If you can show/explain what you really want to calculate there might be a simpler way to get this result, e.g. using OLAP-functions.

Comment: @dnoeth seams to be right about teradata and Lateral Join... most likely you would have to rewrite this into a co-related subquery and use EXISTS kind of approach but without example data and expected results it is hard to know for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
WITH GLT_Yearly as (
      SELECT
      FROM (SELECT
            FROM (SELECT
                  FROM
                 ) GLT0
           ) GLT1
     )
SELECT 
FROM GLT_Yearly LEFT JOIN
     GLT_Yearly BD 
     ON GLT_Yearly.Account = BD.Account;
```

The alias for a subquery can be used to identify columns.  However, it cannot be used as a second reference to the subquery itself.  For that, use a CTE>

Comment: Thank you!! That was what I needed.